# Encryption using Java

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data using AES/ECB using a third party Java code. The data and key is provided. The code is below:-

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class encryptData {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String data="amount=10&expiryDate=20150101 151515&orderRefNum=11001&postBackURL=http://localhost:9081/local/status.php&storeId=28";
    String key="89OUITUPRL3I8H3G";

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    encryptedValue = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes())));
  }
}
```

I am trying it out on https://www.compilejava.net/

This is the error I am getting:-

```
/tmp/java_Ramvov/encryptData.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

encryptedValue = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()))); 
^
symbol: variable encryptedValue

location: class encryptData

/tmp/java_Ramvov/encryptData.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

encryptedValue = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes())));
                                   ^ 
symbol: method encodeBase64(byte[])

location: class Base64
```

2 errors

I have very little knowledge of Java. Please help

Comment: `String encryptedValue = new String(..` you missed the declaration part

Comment: The error is pretty clear  -  encryptedValue  not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You must declare `encryptedValue`, by adding a type before the variable name:

   ```
   String encryptedValue = new String(Base64...
   ```
2. You are using `java.util.Base64` incorrectly.  There is no method `Base64.encodeBase64`. Study the Javadoc for that class and its nested classes `Base64.Decoder` and `Base64.Encoder` to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You never declared encryptedValue. Whenever you get a 'symbol' error, it is usually talking about a variable or a method not existing in a library, this could be from not having declared it.

You would need to add what Pavneet said, or at the very least just have declared encryptedValue earlier.

```
String encryptedValue;
```

at the start of the 'main' method.

Comment: That is more of a comment than an answer. You could explain what the OP needs to do to make it work.

Comment: Fixed? Sorry, i'm new :)